Set options issue When Assigning product attribute programatically in WooCommerce
I have created a form to add the existing attributes (product_attributes) of a product in the front-end.
Everything works fine and the attribute is saved but the values ​​of the attributes are not.
I am passing the attribute values ​​via select2.
    $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
    $attributes = [];
    $variations_name = $_POST['variation_name'];
    $variations = $_POST['variations']; //Select2 Field example: 20,52,98
    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
    foreach ($variations_name as $name) {
        $attribute = new Wc_Product_Attribute();
        $taxonomy = wc_attribute_taxonomy_name($name);
        $attr_id = wc_attribute_taxonomy_id_by_name($taxonomy);
        $attribute->set_id($attr_id);
        $attribute->set_name('pa_' . $name);
        $options = get_term_by('slug', $variations, $taxonomy);
        $attribute->set_options($options); // My problem
        $attribute->set_visible(true);
        $attribute->set_variation(true);
        $attributes[] = $attribute;
        $product->set_attributes(array_merge($attributes, array($taxonomy => $attribute)));
        $product->save();
    }


Note that global attribute values you pass need to be pre-existing term_id(s) so you have to convert them to term IDs, if they are not…
